# how to combine two models in matlab for classification?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, knn, combiners

Hi All I made a NN model for classification and give me what I want also I made KNN which gives me higher accuracy but in my model I want to combine both so both gives me higher accuracy so how I can do that in matlab? ( I am not professional in matlab but now I can understand the code and make the network and knn )

Comment: You can definitely do that with matlab. But which method you're going to use? you may want to do a bit of research before jumping to programming. have a look at [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=667881&tag=1) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensembles_of_classifiers)

Comment: first really thanks for your reply, ÷I will check them, till that if you have any tutorial on how to do the combining please tell me because I am lost here

Comment: Thanks Vahid I read both links and other links so I want to ensemble both NN and KNN using boosting algorithm using AdaBoost and if i can use crossvalidation will be great, so I just want an example so I can create more